# Generating a custom response from a pojo in JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, jax-rs

I have a requirement as follows.

```
Emp{
 String id;
 String name;
}

Employee emp = (Object from service)
builder.entity(emp);
```

but while building reponse as JSON, I would like to generate it as

```
{
 employee_id : val,
 full_name : val,
 //custom attribute in pojo i wanted to inject
 company_url : xxx.com
}
```

Here I dont have access for the Emp class to add the attribute to change the JSON element name using annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `EmpDTO` class annotated with JAXB annotations, instanciate that class in your Resource Method and return it (with all the extra data you need, as you explained), then the JAX-RS implementation would convert the DTO into a JSON message.

Or you could make your own `MessageBodyWriter` (annnotated with `@Producer` + `@Produces("application/json")`) and process the `Emp` class and produce a JSON message (using the JSON-P API for example).

HTH.
Xavier